# Access Attribute of Custom View

Tags: android

I am using [devadvance](https://github.com/devadvance/circularseekbar) Custom view to add Circular Seek bar in my Application. I have successfully added a seek bar to my avtivity but I am not able to access its attributes in xml Layout File.Even in java file i am able to get the reference of seek bar I have added to layout but cant access attributes . 
Structure of my project is as follow

[image]

My xml Layout is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/accent_material_light"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.abhi8569.musicplayer.PlayingNow">

<com.abhi8569.musicplayer.CircularSeekBar
    android:id="@+id/cBar"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/albumArtNowPlaying"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/nowplaying_bg" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there anything else i Need to include for reference?

Comment: did you add attribute and run app,  or just checked auto complete? because auto complete doesnt work some times.

Comment: Have you added the custom view project as a library project? As custom attributes are defined as res, if you simply put the jar file to libs, the build tool cannot locate the res symbols. Check https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryModules to find out how to add a library project.

Comment: Its working now. I don't know how. I gave up and closed Android Studio. Now i opened it again to check what Error i was getting.But its working now. Thank you all for your Concern. How can i Mark this question as answered?